# Is it possible to create graphs in a custom eclipse view?

Tags: eclipse, view

I am creating a custom view in eclipse for a project and I need to be able to bring in data from an outside source and graph it in a custom view. What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'l want to look at the [Graphical Modeling Project (GMP)](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/).  That's where you'll find the base classes to build a custom graphical editor from scratch.  There are also GMP sub-projects that generate graphical editor implementations from EMF models.